# How to remove white spaces which is visible in inspect element

Tags: html, testing, automation

When I inspect element of any webpage text it appears white spaces in its left and right sides. Can somebody tell me how to remove that white spaces around the text. It will help me in automation testing.

Comment: can you show me screen shot ?

Answer (score 1):

do not change the line when you print or type your text

for example

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

do not write/Print like this

```
<p>
some text
</p>
```

this will make space on your code

other solution is, Use Jquery [Trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) but its works Only in i8+

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use .trim() method. Please see link below for reference

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp